# Add DataFrame to Tkinter's tab's

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I need to add a Pandas DataFrame to Tkinter one of the tabs. DataFrame is made from csv file.
I have a code

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Inofin Sprendimai")
root.geometry('500x400')

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)

page1 = ttk.Frame(nb)
page2 = ttk.Frame(nb)
page3 = ttk.Frame(nb)
page4 = ttk.Frame(nb)

nb.add(page1, text='ID And Statistic')
nb.add(page2, text='Table With Names')
nb.add(page3, text="Table With ID's")
nb.add(page4, text='Settings')



nb.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
root.mainloop()`
```

DataFrame should be in the second and third tab of the table...

I can put DataFrame to Tkinter with this code:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry('580x250')

# I put dataframe in here. Now it is just a random df 
dates = pd.date_range('20210101', periods=8)
dframe=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))

txt = Text(root)
txt.pack()

class PrintToTXT(object):
    def write(self, s):
        txt.insert(END, s)

sys.stdout = PrintToTXT()


print (frame)

mainloop()
```

Grateful for any help!

Comment: Does this helps with you problem? https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/python/12494/python-import-csv-file-tkinter-table.html

Comment: thank's for the quick response. I've added scv file to the table already in the second code in my question. The problem is that I don't know how to put that table in GUI's second and third tab (page2 and page3. First code of my question)

Comment: Why not put the text widget in the frame you want? `txt = Text(page2)`